# Booting issue in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, partitioning, boot

I have my new laptop installed with Windows 7 home premium. Yesterday I was trying to partition my hard disk using the pre-installed Disk Management tool in Windows 7. I was unable to do so due to some errors (something like maximum partition reached). I was then fiddling around a bit with it in hope to get it going but I think I unfortunately and unwisely changed the "active partition". I remember I had 4 partitions on my hard disk (as I got from the OEMs) one of 200mb another of 650 gb in which windows is installed then one is 29 gb and the last is 14 mb.

The 200mb one was the active partition and it contained the Bootmgr files. I changed the active partition to the 650gb one and now I can not start my computer as I get the following error after POST:

```
    BOOTMGR is missing
    Press Ctrl+Alt+Del to restart
```

Please let me know how can I fix this. I have the recovery option but I am not sure if the recoverable image is new i.e. I am worried that all my installed programs will be lost if I use this option as it will use the default and pre-installed factory image. Please help me guys.

Also I do not have the Windows 7 cd but I do have bootable ubuntu dvd through which I am able to access the 200mb partition and see the files but I do not know what to change to get Windows running again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Gparted in Ubuntu to set the boot flag for the 200 MB partition.

[You can also use it to backup your stuff to a second drive.](http://gparted.sourceforge.net/larry/move/move.htm)

Answer (score 1):

**Method 1: Startup Repair from the Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE)**

1. Insert the Windows Vista installation disc into the disc drive, and then start the computer.
2. Press a key when the message indicating "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD …". appears.
3. Select a language, a time and currency, and a keyboard or input method, and then click Next.
4. Click Repair your computer.
5. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, choose the drive of your Windows installation and click Next.
6. At the System Recovery Options Dialog Box, click on Repair your computer.
7. Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.
8. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Startup Repair.

**Method 2: Rebuild BCD**

1. Put the Windows Vista installation disc in the disc drive, and then start the computer.
2. Press a key when the message indicating "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD …". appears.
3. Select a language, a time, a currency, and a keyboard or another input method, and then click Next.
4. Click Repair your computer.
5. Click the operating system that you want to repair, and then click Next.
6. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, click Command Prompt.
7. Type Bootrec /RebuildBcd , and then press ENTER.

**Method 3: Use the Windows Recovery Environment (WinRE) to run System Restore (If System Restore is enabled on your computer)**

1. Insert the Windows Vista installation disc into the disc drive, and then start the computer.
2. Press a key when the message indicating "Press any key to boot from CD or DVD …". appears.
3. Select a language, a time and currency, and a keyboard or input method, and then click Next.
4. Click Repair your computer.
5. In the System Recovery Options dialog box, choose the drive of your Windows installation and click Next
6. At the System Recovery Options Dialog Box, click on System Restore.
7. Follow the System Restore Wizard instruction and choose the appropriate restore point.
8. Click Finish to restore the system.